# Setting device wallpaper from flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm fairly new to programming and even newer to `flutter` so go easy on me haha. I'm currently working on my first project in flutter and I would like to add the ability to set wallpapers from my app or at the very least download images to the device gallery. I've had a look at a couple of packages that could help, namely [image_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader#-readme-tab-) and [wallpaper](https://pub.dev/packages/wallpaper). However after adding the packages to the dependencies and trying to test the sample codes neither seem to be working for me. Any help is welcome as I'm struggling to figure out what I need to do!

Answer (score 0):

As far as `image_downloader` package is concerned, here is the code that will work just fine. You might run into `"MissingPluginImplementation"` error while using this package with can be fixed by running these 2 commands in the given sequence:

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Here's a method that I wrote which worked perfectly:

```
    Future<String> download(String url) async {
    try {
      // Saved with this method.
      var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url);

      ImageDownloader.callback(onProgressUpdate: (String imageId, int progress){
        setState(() {
          _progress = progress;
        });
      });

      await pr.show(); // this is progress_dialog package that displays a dialog


      if (imageId == null) {
        return '';
      }
      var location = Platform.isAndroid ? "Downloads" : "Photo Library";
      // Below is a method of obtaining saved image information.
      var fileName = await ImageDownloader.findName(imageId);
      var path = await ImageDownloader.findPath(imageId);
      var size = await ImageDownloader.findByteSize(imageId);
      var mimeType = await ImageDownloader.findMimeType(imageId);

      print("Saved $fileName in $location");
      return fileName;

    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```